# Function to only get certain properties from type depending on parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a set of types/interfaces that have shared properties between them, but some cases don't use them at all and I'd like to create a function where I can only get the properties' names sent to it.

I have these sharedProps:

```
export type sharedProps = {
    className?: string,
    children?: ReactNode
    size?: SIZES_TYPES,
    color?: string;
    altText?: string;
}
```

But sometimes I do not use the `className` foer example. I want a function where I can say `getProperties(['className','children'])` and then it would return a new type/class that would only extend using these two props. Them being optional is not what I need/want, I want them to not be available at all.

Is there a way to do this? Or I'd need to create a case for each combination of props and extend from them?

My current solution is having n number of Types including/excluding properties and extending from them, such as:

```
export type onlyAltText = {
    altText?: string,
}

export type onlyChildren = {
    children?: ReactNode,
}
```

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html. But what's the point, given they're all optional anyway?

Comment: I don't want it to be an option at all when creating x Component, like <Component children={children}/> but inside of it there won't be something to work with the Children for example. I was just checking if it could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

yea you can create a function to pick properties from an object. For the types you can just use `Pick` utility [docs](https://Object.fromEntries(%20%20%20%20%20Object.entries(props).filter((%5Bk%5D)%20=%3E%20targets.includes(k))%20%20%20)%20as%20Pick%3CT,%20K%5Bnumber%5D%3E).

Basically looks something like

```
const pickProps = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  K extends readonly (keyof T)[]
>(
  props: T,
  keys: K
) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(props).filter(([k]) => keys.includes(k))
  ) as Pick<T, K[number]>;
```

So you pass it an object and some array of its keys and will give you object with those keys. Here uses object from entries function but can implement it however you want. We assert the return type because its probably the simplest way to type it, any object mapping in ts is kind of a headache without asserting something. Most cases I don't see the assertion being an issue.

Then you can use it like

```
const props: SharedProps = {
  altText: "text",
  color: "red",
};

const test = pickProps(props, ["className", "altText"]);
console.log(test);
// prints {"altText": "text"}
```

The type of test will be `Pick<SharedProps, "className" | "altText">`
If you want to get rid of Pick in type you can wrap the type return in some expand ts type like

`type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;`

and the type will be

```
const test: {
    className?: string | undefined;
    altText?: string | undefined;
}
```

Here's a typescript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHmAhgOwCYB4AqA%20KBeKTKCOYCNAZygEtkAzCAJygHkoB%20KAbygG0BpGsigBrCCAD2dVgF0AXKwEyoAXygLkEAG5MA3ACh9AYwnIKwKGGpGRABUYSwVAun1RCxUuVRUAShBNGDHNGWgBzABooAFdkEWQJAHdkbAi3KEESMkooRghEVFMAGxAoAAoxSWlMAEpeGX1sMvSwBycFTDT3SooFfn0a-Gx9AHoRgCto8yg6aiKyZgkdZh6oYAkoMIgLRIALRAtJaKhElGBRkeoAWzAiiCvyYAPqUygjFCgAI2hdpO0mKBHE5ndIsT7jALAAB0dAcVxgyGAoQgFGa7ncYIhRmhj2RqNajgoNRhcwWZTKvBEMkGeFwPShtCMRWiqBRFRqNQu6MGiCotmsIiwUX4vGQ0Su30YMmwBncPKo8CQaHQ-JsQoyovFkulMvShlAkCg-kQ2IAchJWfgoAAiY1mi0Qa0GA3QADKAEkAFowV0AfUwAE1bD6rdaPd6-YHg66nfrwG79nlUPZCVauOkmbyKKbEA92AoQuFZW9dnNUHlkPmjfl7azixRqAAvCBV8M%20-1Bn3FkxFCSMKuF5BhYuIeaYLIDpFF-QqAzGUzTAntKCuxMQZNtZzcdKj4Dj0gKa1kUjWrpvCS9xiHpOnmdzkxmCxkaYEKw2FNOMpLihRXjWzMUNmuaOlE1q7vuwDWtSBgPhQF4QFCvZhGUz7ADUBhAA)
Hope it helps , best.